# Kernel Panic Once A Week

Tags: mac, imac, crash, kernel-panic, kernel

I get the exact same kernel panic on my iMac 5K Late 2014 Edition pretty much once a week. Does anyone know what is causing it?

```
Anonymous UUID:       F36129E9-69E1-B321-06F7-0519199C40B7

Tue Mar  6 13:21:08 2018

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff8004d6e339): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80049930c5, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff833b60b688, CR3: 0x00000007a447800d, CR4: 0x00000000001627e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000010, RBX: 0xffffff8050d53bd0, RCX: 0x00000000000004a8, RDX: 0x00000000000081b0
RSP: 0xffffffa3d7073458, RBP: 0xffffffa3d7073490, RSI: 0xffffff8340a0b688, RDI: 0xffffff8340a0b698
R8:  0xffffff8050d53bd0, R9:  0x0000000000001030, R10: 0x0000000413fe3000, R11: 0x0000000000000000
R12: 0x0000000000008158, R13: 0xffffff8050d53bd0, R14: 0x0000000000000815, R15: 0x0000000413feffff
RFL: 0x0000000000010682, RIP: 0xffffff80049930c5, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff833b60b688, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x6, PL: 0, VF: 1

Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
0xffffffa3d7072f00 : 0xffffff8004c4f606 
0xffffffa3d7072f50 : 0xffffff8004d7c654 
0xffffffa3d7072f90 : 0xffffff8004d6e149 
0xffffffa3d7073010 : 0xffffff8004c01120 
0xffffffa3d7073030 : 0xffffff8004c4f03c 
0xffffffa3d7073160 : 0xffffff8004c4edbc 
0xffffffa3d70731c0 : 0xffffff8004d6e339 
0xffffffa3d7073340 : 0xffffff8004c01120 
0xffffffa3d7073360 : 0xffffff80049930c5 
0xffffffa3d7073490 : 0xffffff80052a7f16 
0xffffffa3d70734e0 : 0xffffff7f85cae06e 
0xffffffa3d7073520 : 0xffffff7f85cc3c56 
0xffffffa3d7073550 : 0xffffff7f85c9e1cc 
0xffffffa3d7073580 : 0xffffff7f87ad880d 
0xffffffa3d7073640 : 0xffffff7f85c9bd31 
0xffffffa3d70736b0 : 0xffffff7f85c9b7d7 
0xffffffa3d70736d0 : 0xffffff7f85c9dbfb 
0xffffffa3d7073710 : 0xffffff7f87add448 
0xffffffa3d7073730 : 0xffffff7f85ca5e34 
0xffffffa3d7073760 : 0xffffff7f85cb8b1a 
0xffffffa3d70737a0 : 0xffffff7f85cb8ec3 
0xffffffa3d7073a50 : 0xffffff7f85cb8196 
0xffffffa3d7073aa0 : 0xffffff7f85cb7fa4 
0xffffffa3d7073ae0 : 0xffffff7f85cb7206 
0xffffffa3d7073b20 : 0xffffff80052b85d8 
0xffffffa3d7073b70 : 0xffffff80052c1437 
0xffffffa3d7073cb0 : 0xffffff8004d28894 
0xffffffa3d7073dc0 : 0xffffff8004c54c40 
0xffffffa3d7073e10 : 0xffffff8004c31cbd 
0xffffffa3d7073e60 : 0xffffff8004c44b7b 
0xffffffa3d7073ef0 : 0xffffff8004d5857d 
0xffffffa3d7073fa0 : 0xffffff8004c01926 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(376.6)[5F8F39B4-41AB-3263-9867-D0FAF9BBD2AE]@0xffffff7f85c84000->0xffffff7f85d19fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[498548AE-30A0-36C6-92F7-1714D01C0A98]@0xffffff7f85bff000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(209.2.2)[AE58720D-7079-388F-AD95-FD2366F98F8D]@0xffffff7f85c14000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[8E6C654E-4A8F-3C6B-BBFE-BA8A68C9C146]@0xffffff7f85494000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(517.22)[2AEA02BF-2A38-3674-A187-E5F610FD65B7]@0xffffff7f85c30000
         com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000(1.6)[1069DE07-9A4D-3E0D-8664-1906A6A08124]@0xffffff7f87ac8000->0xffffff7f8834afff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(209.2.2)[AE58720D-7079-388F-AD95-FD2366F98F8D]@0xffffff7f85c14000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[8E6C654E-4A8F-3C6B-BBFE-BA8A68C9C146]@0xffffff7f85494000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(517.22)[2AEA02BF-2A38-3674-A187-E5F610FD65B7]@0xffffff7f85c30000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(376.6)[5F8F39B4-41AB-3263-9867-D0FAF9BBD2AE]@0xffffff7f85c84000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
17D102

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 18D901F1-4A03-3FF1-AE34-C26B2732F13C
Kernel slide:     0x0000000004800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8004900000
System model name: iMac15,1 (Mac-42FD25EABCABB274)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 518761777373640
last loaded kext at 518582575721778: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub  900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f88e4c000, size 12288)
last unloaded kext at 518336103472840: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub    900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f88e4c000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.github.osxfuse.filesystems.osxfuse  3.7.1
com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost 8.1.1
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.30
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   280.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.16.21
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.3.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.3.0
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  748.41.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.30.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1220.28.1a3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.16.21
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.22
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    376.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209.2.2
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.2
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.21
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.22
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.2f2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.2f2
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.6.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.40.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.30.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.30.4
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140.30.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.30.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    650.5
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: iMac15,1, BootROM IM151.0211.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 4 GHz, 32 GB, SMC 2.22f16
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M290X, AMD Radeon R9 M290X, PCIe, 2 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331302D38475351000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331302D38475351000000
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331302D38475351000000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x04CD, 0x46332D313630304331302D38475351000000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x142), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.5.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.2f2, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: JMicron
USB Device: USB3.0 Hub
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: iPhone
USB Device: USB2.0 Hub
USB Device: LUXAFOR FLAG
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Usb Mouse
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 26.1
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea, but have you loaded any unusual drivers or system extensions? Any Kext's?

Comment: It might be hw/graphics card related (com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000).  Try running [Apple HW Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) and see what you get.

Comment: I ran Apple Diagnostic test and it showed up with no errors. Does it test RAM by any chance?